# React Native. How to place two Text with different fontSize in row with vertical align center

Tags: react-native, react-native-stylesheet

I need to align two `Text` component with different `fontSize` in a row and vertically centered. I have following now https://snack.expo.io/@troublediehard/dmVuZ2

[image]

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.row}>
          <Text style={styles.text1}>Font size 20</Text>
          <Text style={styles.text2}>Font size 14</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  row: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    backgroundColor: 'red',
  },
  text1: {
    fontSize: 20,
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
  },
  text2: {
    fontSize: 14,
    backgroundColor: 'green',
  },
});
```

Comment: hey, ever found a solution to this?

Comment: @Return-1 check answer and comments below, there whole story. Looks like it was issue with custom font and stick with padding workaround.

Comment: hmm i wonder though if this solution would work uniformly to all devices. I too am using a custom ( albeit not rare ) font and it seems like the size of the Text is higher than the text itself which means that text doesnt align properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add `alignItems: 'center'` to `styles.row`

```
row: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'red',
},
```

Comment: thanks, it works for my sample, but actually doesn't work in my project with custom fonts.

Comment: It should vertically align the content, unless there is some other padding or margin involved.

Comment: works if I removing `fontFamily` from style, but not working with custom font.

Comment: Not sure if it is the line-height issue with the font, try adjusting using `lineHeight`

Comment: I've tried, but not helped as well. I gave up on this, looks like some issue here, I simply added padding to center second font.

Answer (score 9):

For anyone that didn't found a solution yet, you have to wrap the text within another Text tag:

```
<View style={styles.container}>
  <View style={styles.row}>
    <Text>
      <Text style={styles.text1}>Font size 20</Text>
      <Text style={styles.text2}>Font size 14</Text>
    </Text>
  </View>
</View>
```

Comment: and set the Text wrapper to the smallest font size

Comment: I used it, works fine 