# Loop <Text> through array and display it side by side in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have an array that is filled with an object containing two keys i.e name of HTML tag as **name** and text as **text**. I am looping through all the object of an array and then comparing **object['name']** to fixed tag name for such as ***strong , h1 , h2 , pre , var*** and displaying text content using a component with the style that I prefer inside each if block like :

```
     const TagSelector = function(tagName , $text , $key){
  
        if(tagName == "strong"){
            return <Text  key={$key} style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' , paddingHorizontal:3 , paddingVertical:10}}>{$text}</Text>
        }

        if(tagName == "h1"){
          return <H2 key={$key} >{$text}</H2>
        }

        if(tagName == "h2"){
           return <H3 key={$key} style={{paddingHorizontal:5 , paddingVertical:5 }}>{$text}</H3>
        }

        if(tagName == "pre"){
           return <Text  key={$key} style={{ fontSize:11 , paddingHorizontal:7 , paddingVertical:7 ,  borderColor: '#d8d7d7', borderWidth: 1 , backgroundColor:'#eee' ,   borderRadius:10, margin:5 }}>{$text}</Text>
        }

        if(tagName == "var"){
            return <View style={{flexDirection:'row', flexWrap:'wrap' ,  justifyContent:'space-between'}}><Text key={$key} style={{backgroundColor:'red' , color:'black' }}>{$text}</Text> 
           </View> 
        }
     }
```

My Object :

```
         var collection = [{
            "name": "p",
            "text": "Keywords are ..... . For example:"
         }, {
            "name": "var",
            "text": "int"
         }, {
            "name": "var",
            "text": " money;"
         }, {
            "name": "var",
            "text": "Here, "
         },
         {
            "name": "strong",
            "text": "This is fine "
         }]
```

Looping Function:

```
     const ContentScreen = () => {
         return <ScrollView style={{paddingHorizontal:12, marginTop:10}}>
               {
                 collection.map((con , index)=>{
                  return TagSelector(con.name , con.text , index+'_Tags');
               })
          }
          </ScrollView>
     }
```

Problem :

In case of ***var*** I want to create such style which displays ***side by side of the first letter*** Expected Output :

```
     Keywords are ...... For example:
     int money; Here,
     **This is fine**
```

[This is Output that I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Ea3A.png)

What I tried :

1. I went through official documentation of react native [This](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flexbox)
2. Stackoverflow answer 1 [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34624100/simulate-display-inline-in-react-native)
3. Stackoverflow answer 2 [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53364901/react-native-how-to-place-two-text-with-different-fontsize-in-row-with-vertical) , etc

**I couldn't solve this problem please help me.**

Answer (score -1):

This is output I got when I tried.

[image]

Here's the code:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {View, Text} from 'react-native';

const App = () => {
  const [data] = useState([
   {
     name: 'p',
     text: 'Keywords are ..... . For example:',
   },
   {
     name: 'var',
     text: 'int',
   },
   {
     name: 'var',
     text: ' money;',
   },
   {
     name: 'var',
     text: 'Here, ',
   },
   {
     name: 'strong',
     text: 'This is fine ',
   },
 ]);

 const renderElements = () => {
   let jsx = [];
   let varElements = [];

   data.forEach((item) => {
      if (item.name === 'var') {
       varElements.push(<Text>{item.text}</Text>);
      } else {
       if (varElements.length > 0) {
         jsx.push(<View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>{varElements}</View>);
       }
       varElements = [];
       jsx.push(<Text>{item.text}</Text>);
     }
   });

   return jsx;
 };

   return <View>{renderElements()}</View>;
};

export default App;
```

The magic happens inside renderElements function.

1. `let jsx = []` <--- This is the overall generated JSX.
2. `let varElements = []` <-- We temporarily store reoccurring var elements inside them and then push to JSX.
3. We loop the array with forEach and check every element, if the element is var type then we add it inside `varElements` else we check if we already have some `varElements` if we have then we group them inside `<View/>` with `flexDirection:'row';` and push them to JSX array. Then we empty the varElements array and push the other type of element to JSX.

Comment: This is not what was asked!